# How do I best simulate a check for contiguous storage before C++20?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, containers, contiguous

C++20 added the [`contiguous_iterator` trait](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/contiguous_iterator), which I can (?) use on a container's iterators to determine whether it has contiguous storage.

But - what if I can only rely on C++11? What's the closest I can get to determining whether a type (let's say it's guaranteed to be a container) has contiguous storage? I realize the answer may not be entirely reliable, or may not cover all cases, but I want to use some  "best-effort" kind of function for this.

Comment: anything with a `data()` member should have contagious storage.

Comment: @NathanOliver - contiguous vs contagious: ☺

Comment: @selbie lol, auto correct fail.

Comment: Have a typedef in your library `lib::contiguous_iterator_tag` that aliases the standard one if C++20 is detected or a unique type otherwise. Then tell users to use that tag. Fallback to a list of predefined types and heuristics (e.g. `data()`) if the tag isn't used, and possibly warn users if heuristics aren't very reliable.

Answer (score 2):

Make it a trait on the container or range.

Arrays and std arrays are contiguous.

Vectors are contiguous as are std strings.

String views and std spans are also contiguous.

If you allow for easy extension, simply list all of the contiguous containers.

Or, if you want to be lazy and are ok with a heuristic, arrays, plus objects with `T* data()` and `std::size_t size() const` where `*x.begin()` is `T&`.

But really the types I listed, plus at most a half-dozen custom types in your code base, are going to be it.  List them explicitly.  It won't grow without bounds because you'll eventually upgrade to C++20.

Comment: Well, that brings up a different question of when it's legitimate to have your library depend on a newer C++ version, when you don't really need the newer version for anything. I mean, `std::contiguous_iterator` is not enough of a motivation. Anyway, I was also thinking about checking for `T* data()`.

Comment: @einpoklum If your library exposes non-trivial templates, requires clauses make your API much much better: errors that say what goes wrong, instead of pages of recursive template spam, and requirements that can be read without understanding template metaprogramming.  All by itself it would be a legitimate upgrade.

Comment: It only exposes some trivial templates. Or templates on some enum value. But your point is well-taken. A significant benefit for me would be the availability of `std::span` and `std::optional`.